# access denied when putting a bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to put a bucket policy on an S3 bucket with following rule. I am getting error **access denied** while doing so.

```
{
        "Sid": "Deny bucket/policy delete",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnNotEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/role_name"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to put the same rule on other buckets in the account, so can confirm the IAM role has permissions.

I am able to put other rules on this bucket so can confirm have permissions to put policy on this bucket as well. I am able to delete the bucket policy as well. One of the successful rule is as below:

```
{
        "Sid": "Deny http access",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
            }
        }
    }
```

Successful rule is for bucket/*

Failed rule is on bucket.

If IAM role is not restricting what else could be the issue? Not sure what I am missing. Please suggest.

ACL Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you check ACL ?

Comment: @JunedAhsan ACL doesnt seem to be a prob. Added screenshot.

Comment: Check this : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/

Comment: @JunedAhsan Already gone through the link. checked IAM and Bucket policies. The role I am using is kind of admin role, so permissions is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by mentioning that you are adding a 'dangerous' Bucket Policy in that, if you get it wrong, you will only be able to remove it by using the root login. This is because it could, if coded incorrectly, Deny everyone from touching the Bucket Policy.

Rather than using a condition, you could probably use a `NotPrincipal`. See: [AWS JSON Policy Elements: NotPrincipal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html)

Also, check the settings of **Block S3 Public Access**, which can block the creation of a Bucket Policy.

Comment: yes, the 'dangerous' bucket policy is the intention. Agree, could use 'NotPrincipal' as well, will look into it. Coming to Blocked policy, apparently thats a bug with AW, raised a support ticket and getting it looked into now.

Comment: @14578446 Is there any update on this, perhaps?  Was this indeed a bug, or a misunderstood feature?  It seems today we ran into the same issue: a 'blocked public access' bucket where setting an access policy resulted in access denied (and setting blocked=off made it work). In our case the IAM user has full permissions (administrator role) and the access policy is really simple (only s3:GetObject permission of a single prefix).  The only special thing, is that the policy allows access for a role in a different AWS account.  [And in another set of accounts, the exact same thing did _not_ error.]

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica I don't quite understand your situation, but **S3 Block Public Access** is _not_ a bug. It is an intentional additional level of safeguard to prevent buckets being accidentally exposed. If you are wanting to provide bucket access to a specific IAM User, you should be granting that access via a policy on the IAM User rather than adding it as a Bucket Policy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks! Is there AWS documentation that says, "If S3 Block Public Access is on, then it is not allowed to set the bucket policy for that bucket"?  Because that is what is happening for us.  (But strangely enough only in one account, while in another account the same thing works fine.)  (And the actual bucket policy we put there, in this case was the same as the policy already there.)  (And we _have_ to set the bucket access policy, because the role we want to let into the bucket is from a different AWS account.  (Yes, I know about AssumeRole :-), going to switch to that.))

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica Using a Bucket Policy to permit access from another AWS Account is fine, and is often preferable to requiring use of an IAM Role. For example, if you were wanting to copy data between S3 buckets from different AWS Accounts, you will need to use one set of credentials that has access to _both_ buckets. This can be done with a Bucket Policy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Exactly. But the 'put bucket policy' call failed with an 'access denied' error, until S3 Block Public Access was switched off.  (This happened for us, and apparently also for the OP, per their initial comment on this answer.) Is there any explanation for that behavior? Any related AWS documentation? Or is there a bug report somewhere that confirms "apparently thats a bug with AW"S?

Comment: @MarnixKloosterReinstateMonica That is working 100% correctly -- the option says "S3 will block new bucket and access point policies that grant public access to buckets and objects." The [Blocking public access to your Amazon S3 storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) documentation explains it further as "Setting this option to TRUE for a bucket causes Amazon S3 to reject calls to PUT Bucket policy if the specified bucket policy allows public access".